# Network error on powershell SQL job step

Tags: sql, sql-server, powershell, sql-server-2014, sql-job

This is partially  my code and partially from others help here on stack overflow.

```
$excelFile = "C:\ExcelTest\Test.csv"
$functionDirectory = "C:\foldername"


$csv = Import-csv $excelFile -Header FileName

Import-Module sqlps

foreach ($line in $csv) 
    {
    if(test-path -path ($functionDirectory + "\" + $line.FileName))
        {
        invoke-sqlcmd -inputfile "C:\foldername\filename.sql" -serverinstance "servername\instancename" -database "databasename"
        }
    }
```

I had to remove the specific serverinstance / servername for privacy but I've checked both of those several times and I don't think that is where the issue is.  I keep getting the error

> A network related or instance specific error occurred while
>   establishing a connection to SQL Server.  The server was not found or
>   was not accessible.  Verify that the instance name is correct and that
>   SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections.

I have double checked server / instance name which I got from the server by running

```
select @@servername + '\' + @@SERVICENAME
```

nd the database name obviously was easy to get.  I have double checked that the server is set up for remote connection (even though this is a database that is local on my laptop and not a remote server currently).

I'm kinda at a loss for what else to check for.

I had read you should look at firewall settings  but I don't think those should make a difference when its a local server on my machine.

I'm still somewhat new with SQL and powershell so I apologize for any blatant syntax or formatting errors (please point out so I can correct them).  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You might need to enable TCP/IP connections in SQL server configuration manager as well as ensure that the port number is the default 1433, otherwise you will need to specify the port as well.

Comment: I believe that the `servername/instancename` should use a backwards slash: `servername\instancename`.

Comment: @Lukos Does that matter since its a local server and I'm not remoting to it??

Comment: @TomH Ya was a typo on my part, the actual code has the correct backwards.

Comment: Yes it does matter. It needs to connect somehow. If you use named pipes or shared memory, the connection string can be different. When you say it is running locally, do you mean in a VM or on the same OS? If so, try using (local) instead of server\instance

Comment: @Lukos By locally I mean on the same OS.

Comment: @Lukos I tried local and get an error saying its not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script, or operable function.  Without the parentheses just gives the same error as previous.

Comment: are you able to connect to the sql server instance through SSMS from the same computer you are trying to run the PS scripts?

Comment: @Nirman Yes, I'm connected to that server through SSMS and trying to set up the SQL job through the same instance of SSMS.

Comment: Can you try specifying servername\instancename without quotes?

Comment: @Nirman Same error.  I'm beginning to think its some local network settings on my machine as other computers in our office are able to hit a different remote server that I am unable to.

Comment: yes, there can be many possible reasons. May be this has something to do with the firewall on your machine, if its turned on.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I needed to remove the instance name and just use the server name.